# Beginner Matrix Access in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-guide

Now first off, I am not even sure this is called a matrix, and I am new to MATLAB. But let's say I have a "matrix" that looks like this:

```
for n=1:10
...
someImage = mat(:,:,n) %The "matrix"
...
end
```

where `n` could be the frames in a video, for example, and the first 2 `':'` are the row and column data for the 2D image (the frame).

If I only wanted the first `':'` of data (the row? column? element?), how would I access only that?

Intuitively, I think something like:

```
row1 = mat(:,0,0)
row2 = mat(0,:,0)
row3 = mat(0,0,:)
```

but that doesn't seem to be working.

P.S. I know that these aren't really rows, the terminology for all this would also be greatly appreciated

Also, it may not have anything to do with this, but I am using a MATLAB GUI as well, and the "matrix" is stored like this:

```
handles.mat(:,:,n)
```

I don't think it has anything to do with my actual question, but it might so I will put it here

-Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One point I would like to make before starting:  MATLAB starts indexing at **1**, and not **0**.  This is a common mistake that most people who have a C/Java/Python programming background make going into MATLAB.

Also, by doing:

```
row1 = mat(:,1,1);
```

This accesses all of the rows for the first column and the first frame of your video.  Be aware that this will produce a `M x 1` vector, where `M` denotes the number of rows for a frame in your video.

Also:

```
row2 = mat(1,:,1);
```

This accesses all of the columns in the first row of the first frame.  Be aware that this will produce a `1 x N` vector, where `N` denotes the number of columns for a frame in your video.

Also:

```
row3 = mat(1,1,:);
```

This accesses all of the pixels in the **entire** video sequence at row 1 and column 1.  You can think of this as a temporal slice at the top left corner of your video sequence.  Be aware that this will produce a `1 x 1 x T` vector, where `T` is the number of frames in your video.  If you access just a single pixel location in your video, the first two dimensions are superfluous, and so you can use the `squeeze` command to shrink all of the singleton dimensions so that it simplifies to a `T x 1` vector.  In other words, do this:

```
row3 = squeeze(mat(1,1,:));
```

FWIW, you do have the right terminology.  Rows and columns are used in image / video processing all the time.  As for the "matrix", you can call this a **temporal sequence** or a **frame sequence** in terms of video processing.  It certainly is a 3D matrix, but people in this domain denote it as either one of the two as it is really a sequence of images / frames stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Wow, extremely insightful answer, thanks for the time!

Comment: @SeanSenWang: You're very welcome!  This kind of stuff I do daily and I love doing it :)  If it helps, I also struggled with MATLAB when I started with this stuff the first time.  One of the biggest "gotchas" that I was still trying to get used to was the 0/1 indexing.  It was the most common error I made, and it took a while to be able to switch back and forth between MATLAB and C/Java/Python.  Good luck!